# How to create copy of class object without any reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create a copy of a class object without any reference? `ICloneable` makes a copy of a class object (via shallow copy) but doesn't support deep copying. I am looking for a function that is smart enough to read all members of a class object and make a deep copy to another object without specifying member names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone Whole Object Graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417023/clone-whole-object-graph)

Comment: Quick and dirty solution is to serialize the object and immediately deserialize to another object. Of course that depends upon whether the object can be properly serialized...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this as a solution, basically write your own function to do this since what you said about ICloneable not doing a deep copy

```
public static T DeepCopy(T other)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, other);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

I'm referencing this thread.  [copy a class, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031023/copy-a-class-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static object Clone(object obj)
    {
        object new_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite && pi.PropertyType.IsSerializable)
            {
                pi.SetValue(new_obj, pi.GetValue(obj, null), null);
            }
        }
        return new_obj;
    }
```

You can adjust to your needs. For example,

```
if (pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite && 
       (pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) || 
        pi.PropertyType == typeof(int) || 
        pi.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    )
{
    pi.SetValue(new_obj, pi.GetValue(obj, null), null);
}
```

OR

```
if (pi.CanRead && pi.CanWrite && 
    (pi.PropertyType.IsEnum || pi.PropertyType.IsArray))
{
    ...;
}
```